# Фоновая картинка (параллакса) при движении курсора прыгает, как это исправить в скрипте?

Tags: javascript

У меня фоновая картинка (параллакса) при движении курсора прыгает потому что курсор заходит на другие блоки которые сверху фоновой картинки.

В этом же скрипте, надо сделать как-то так чтобы курсор не видел другие блоки относительно параллакса и картинка не прыгала.

*Прописать в стилях например `transition: 0.2s;` для плавного скачка или другие костыли, не подходит.*

*Помогите, пожалуйста, кто знает как это сделать, с готовым решением, буду очень благодарен.*

Вот [пример](https://codepen.io/roms24/pen/mdmBrmR) с тем же скриптом *(при наведении на блок с текстом, фоновая картинка прыгает)*:

**html**

```
 <div  class="module" style="padding: 200px">
  <div class="module-novis">Text</div>
</div>
```

**css**

```
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: none;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  list-style: none;
}
.module {
  background: url(https://www.google.com.ua/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png) no-repeat;
  background-size: 400px;
  background-position: var(--x ) var(--y) ;
}
.module-novis{
    font-size: 70px; 
    padding:10px; 
    text-align: center; 
    background: #cccc ;
}
```

**js**

```
const el = document.querySelector(".module");

el.addEventListener("mousemove", (e) => {
  el.style.setProperty('--x', -e.offsetX / 100 + 60 + "%");
  el.style.setProperty('--y', -e.offsetY / 50 + 60 + "%");
});
```

Comment: Для начала выложите пример, который можно запустить.

Comment: @nazarpunk Добавил ссылку в описании вопроса. Может это поможет? codepen.io/roms24/pen/mdmBrmR

Comment: Не знаю будет ли для вас это костылём. Задайте дочерним элементам стиль `pointer-events: none` и они вообще будут игнорировать мышь и тач. Или используйте pageX вместо offsetX, и прибавляйте/отнимайте позицию блока.

Comment: @PavelGrishaev ` pointer-events: none; ` уже пробовал раньше, это помогает но это костыли. мне надо чтобы контент тех блоков взаимодействовал с клиентом. Более помогла замена `offsetХ` на `clientХ`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Заменил `offsetXY` на `clientXY` и прыгать перестало.

```js
const el = document.querySelector(".module");

el.addEventListener("mousemove", (e) => {
  el.style.setProperty('--x', -e.clientX / 100 + 60 + "%");
  el.style.setProperty('--y', -e.clientY / 50 + 60 + "%");
});
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: none;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  list-style: none;
}
.module {
  background: url(https://www.google.com.ua/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png) no-repeat;
  background-size: 400px;
  background-position: var(--x ) var(--y);
}
.module-novis{
    font-size: 70px; 
    padding:10px; 
    text-align: center; 
    background: #cccc ;
}
```

```html
 <div  class="module" style="padding: 200px">
  <div class="module-novis">Text</div>
</div>
```